# JavaScript: Function in loop declaration performance. Arrow function vs function outside loop

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a function `activeElemFromPoint`. It is called many times on mouse moves.

The questions are:

1. I have to use option 3 (Function outside loop)?
2. Are function `hasEvtNoAttr` declarations 3.1 and 3.2 equivalent?

Option 1. Arrow function

```js
/** @param { {clientX:number, clientY:number} } evt */
export function activeElemFromPoint(evt) {
    return document
        .elementsFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
        .find(el => !el.hasAttribute('data-evt-no'));
}
```

Option 2. Function inside loop

```js
/** @param { {clientX:number, clientY:number} } evt */
export function activeElemFromPoint(evt) {
    return document
        .elementsFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
        .find(function (el) { return !el.hasAttribute('data-evt-no'); });
}
```

Option 3. Function outside loop

```js
/** @param { {clientX:number, clientY:number} } evt */
export function activeElemFromPoint(evt) {
    return document
        .elementsFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
        .find(hasEvtNoAttr);
}

// 3.1
/** @param {Element} el */
const hasEvtNoAttr = (el) => !el.hasAttribute('data-evt-no');

// 3.2
function hasEvtNoAttr(el) { return !el.hasAttribute('data-evt-no'); }
```

As I know Option 1 will create new function every time.

Comment: Why are you worried about this? js engines are quite good at optimizing such things.

Comment: Take a look at this benchmark https://jsben.ch/xD8Xx It seems like moving functions outside is worse